# Load Balancing Misbehaving

Tags: sharepoint-server, load-balancing

We have a web SharePoint farm with 4 WFE's.

When testing the load balancing, we noticed that when we down a specific WFE, the whole farms stops working (**no requests are processed**).

When any of the other three are brought down (each on its own), the farm works fine.